# UniqueEntity as standalone constraint in @validator->validate

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working on a request ParamFetcher inspired from the [FOSRestBundle ParamFetcher](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSRestBundle/param_fetcher_listener.html).

The [ParamFetcher](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Request/ParamFetcher.php) is used to validate and retrieve params from the request body in a Controller action.

Each parameter can have one or more requirements that can be a Regex or another Constraint (e.g. the "[Email constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Email.html).).

To validate one of them, I use the following:

```
// ...
$paramKey = 'email';
$paramValue = $this->getRequest()->request->get($paramKey);
$constraint = new Email();
$errors = $this->get('validator')->validate($paramValue, $constraint);
// if 0 !== count($errors) then throws an exception
```

How can I use the same behavior with the [UniqueEntity](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html) constraint ?

I don't (and can't) use any FormType on which perform assertions, and the default usage of the constraint is to map it to the corresponding field in the corresponding entity, but the field need to be set dynamically from the action directly.

Maybe pass the entity namespace as second argument to the constraint in order to use `EntityManager::findOneBy([$paramKey => $paramValue])` from the constraint validator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UniqueEntity is a class constraint, it means that `validate` method receives an object as the first parameter. Like this:

```
$this->get('validator')->validate($obj, new UniqueEntity(FIELD));
```

You can also create your own validation constraint as [described here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) if your validation logic is complex.

Comment: Thanks for your input. The `validate` does not take a value in this case, So do I need to set the value in the object through accessor ?

Comment: @chalasr I don't think it is good idea to set a value through accessor. May be you should create your custom constraint validator?

Comment: So it's not possible to make my validation using the default UniqueEntity ? The validator cannot validate if there is no value to check duplicate, right ?  And yes, if there is no other solution I'll built my own constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I used the following to achieve this :

```
$param = new RequestParam('email', 'AcmeBundle\FooEntity', array('unique' => true));
// prototype:  RequestParam::__construct($field, $class, array $requirements);

if (true === $params->requirements['unique']) {
    $object = new $config->class;
    $accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();

    if ($accessor->isWritable($object, $name)) {
        $accessor->setValue($object, $name, $param);
    }

    $errors = $this->validator->validate($object, $constraint);

    // ...
}
```

If the param require to be `unique`, I used the class passed as argument, create an instance of it, set the unique field, and make the validation on the object.

I'll surely create my own to avoid the object creation that is useless after validation, and use `EntityManager::findOneBy([params])` to perform validation directly from the returned result.